# find('all') return two different queries

Tags: cakephp

I am using cake1.3 , I have two models : -

```
class Patient extends AppModel {
var $hasMany = array(
    'ConsultingDet' => array(
        'className' => 'ConsultingDet',
        'foreignKey' => 'patient_id',           
    )
);
}

class ConsultingDet extends AppModel {
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Patient' => array(
        'className' => 'Patient',
        'foreignKey' => 'patient_id',
    )   ''
    );
}
```

When I use

```
$patients = $this->Patient->find('all')
```

The sqldump shows two queries, one is select fields from patients and second is a join query between consulting and patient. (Which only I actually needed.).
As it results two different queries I cant add condition to it?
Why find is returning so?

Comment: Do you have any relation (hasMany) defined in Patient model?If you have defined hasMany relation then it will run two queries

Comment: you can only left join in the "belongsTo" direction. otherwise it is a separate query and therefore two totally different outcomes (the latter cannot use conditions from the second query in the first, of course). so beware of the direction of your query.

Comment: what conditions do you want to set?

Comment: I want to fetch all patients where ConsultingDet.visit=0. This will not work in first query because query showing no relation with ConsultDet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cake does not do a left join in case of hasMany relations, only in case of belongsTo. So if you do it the other way around (`$this->ConsultingDet->find('all')`), cake should run one query.

If you want to apply different conditions for these two tables, you'll just have to run two queries manually.

There is a way around this by customizing 'joins' param in cake's query, if you want to experiment with that.